# The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.3.1) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.2.1 (React-native)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I recently created a new React-Native project with a (0.71) version.
When I opened the project in the Android Studio it is giving me the below error while Building.

> The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.3.1) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.2.1

I searched for this but I found a solution which is upgrading Android Studio.

Is there any other solution for these?

Answer (score 1):

with this error come a redirect url talking about a table of compatibility https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?hl=fr#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility

I updated Android Studio to the latest (Electric Eel 2022.1.1) and gradle build succesfully

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You edit does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you think this does not answer the question, please delete it.